# a complicated query by laravel eloquent orm

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

projects

id, name

projects_services(1 project_id <-> M service_id)

project_id, service_id

services

id, name

services_modules(M service_id <-> N module_id)

service_id, module_id

modules

id, name

modules_scripts(1 module_id<->1 script_id)

module_id, script_id

scripts

id, name

How can I query the follow infomation by `scripts` object?

script_id, script_name, module_name, service_name, project_name

Answer (score 0):

```
$script->id;
$script->name;
$script->modules_script->module->name;
```

So on and so forth. Why you would need to do this baffles me me but if you really need to get everything through the script object and your relationships are set up correctly that should work.